# CodeIgniter how to get hidden field value using form_open_multipart()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a web application that allows user to insert item data into database.  insert_item page is just a regular HTML form.  When user submits, the controller inserts item data into Item table, and then redirects user to insert_image page.  In this page, I have a hidden field that contains the item_id (primary key for Item table).  This page contains upload file form.

```
echo form_open_multipart('administration/validate_add_images');
form_hidden('id', $id);
$this->table->add_row(array(form_upload('uploads')));
form_submit('submit', 'Upload Images');
```

I can't get the value of id when user submits.  My question: Is it possible to get the hidden field value  using form_open_multipart()?

Comment: it would be helpful to see the `administration/validate_add_images` controller function.

Comment: This is an old question, but aren't you supposed to `echo` form-helper functions? (`echo form_hidden('id', $id);`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to access it just like any other form field

```
$this->input->post('id');
```

Comment: Tried to echo it and got nothing.

Comment: Solved it.  I forgot to echo the form_hidden.

Answer (score 1):

you can also get to display all your POST ARRAY like this

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
```